# Rollapplyr with multiple columns by group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rollapply

I have timeseries data with multiple values and categorical grouping variables. I would like to calculate the running average for each value, per group. My data includes NAs for some timesteps, that I want to be ignored when calculating the rolling mean. I found several questions and answers on this on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions worked so far and I'm wondering what I'm missing. I know I could do this in long format, but I have several other categorical variables that I want to retain untouched.

```
df[1:10,]
             Timestamp     val1     val2 group
1  2018-03-28 10:56:14       NA       NA     2
2  2018-03-28 10:56:18 152.4206 150.2132     2
3  2018-03-28 10:56:30 140.1681 140.4355     2
4  2018-03-28 10:56:38 141.4961 140.6526     2
5  2018-03-28 10:56:40 140.0825 139.0457     2
6  2018-03-28 10:56:42 140.0453 140.0724     2
7  2018-03-28 10:56:44 140.7152 140.6107     2
8  2018-03-28 10:56:46 137.1136 137.7038     2
9  2018-03-28 10:56:52 138.1676 138.1061     2
10 2018-03-28 10:57:00 139.7503 138.8120     2

df.sma<-as.data.frame(df%>%
                        group_by(group)%>%
                        mutate(across(2:3, rollapplyr, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE, by = 1, partial = TRUE, fill = NA
                        )))

> head(df.sma)
            Timestamp     val1     val2 group
1 2018-03-28 10:56:14      NaN      NaN     2
2 2018-03-28 10:56:18 152.4206 150.2132     2
3 2018-03-28 10:56:30 146.2944 145.3243     2
4 2018-03-28 10:56:38 144.6950 143.7671     2
5 2018-03-28 10:56:40 143.5419 142.5867     2
6 2018-03-28 10:56:42 142.8425 142.0839     2

df.sma2<-as.data.frame(df%>%
                        group_by(group)%>%
                        mutate_at(vars(2:3), rollapplyr, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE, by = 1, partial = TRUE, fill = NA)%>%
                        ungroup())

head(df.sma2)
            Timestamp     val1     val2 group
1 2018-03-28 10:56:14      NaN      NaN     2
2 2018-03-28 10:56:18 152.4206 150.2132     2
3 2018-03-28 10:56:30 146.2944 145.3243     2
4 2018-03-28 10:56:38 144.6950 143.7671     2
5 2018-03-28 10:56:40 143.5419 142.5867     2
6 2018-03-28 10:56:42 142.8425 142.0839     2
```

some example data:

```
df<-structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1522270574, 1522270578, 
1522270590, 1522270598, 1522270600, 1522270602, 1522270604, 1522270606, 
1522270612, 1522270620, 1522270624, 1522270626, 1522270630, 1522270638, 
1522270646, 1522270650, 1522270652, 1522270656, 1522270658, 1522270666, 
1522270672, 1522270674, 1522270678, 1522270682, 1522270684, 1522270700, 
1522270704, 1522270706, 1522270710, 1522270712, 1522270714, 1522270720, 
1522270728, 1522270732, 1522270736, 1522270742, 1522270760, 1522270764, 
1522270766, 1522270770, 1522270788, 1522270792, 1522270796, 1522270800, 
1522270808, 1522270814, 1522270820, 1522270828, 1522270832, 1522270858, 
1522272018, 1522272022, 1522272038, 1522272042, 1522272044, 1522272045, 
1522272047, 1522272048, 1522272049, 1522272051, 1522272052, 1522272053, 
1522272055, 1522272056, 1522272068, 1522272070, 1522272071, 1522272072, 
1522272074, 1522272075, 1522272077, 1522272079, 1522272080, 1522272081, 
1522272083, 1522272084, 1522272086, 1522272094, 1522272096, 1522272097, 
1522272099, 1522272100, 1522272102, 1522272104, 1522272105, 1522272108, 
1522272116, 1522272142, 1522272150, 1522272154, 1522272162, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "HST"), val1 = c(NA, 152.420640676898, 140.168146874079, 
141.496126708293, 140.082529977673, 140.045275612881, 140.715183202103, 
137.113586611079, 138.16758361454, 139.75031798328, 140.215984869446, 
139.764008780732, 140.037498184457, 139.200923807515, 138.761322782691, 
139.228081249134, 140.132374508114, 140.603522297505, 140.303591344302, 
138.79444324265, 138.592897758994, 138.933406279942, 136.231013692759, 
139.381687594324, 140.308379184618, 137.223670050664, 139.508300292213, 
139.405762972775, 140.498207629702, 140.557352578793, 141.007893031604, 
138.469342717392, 138.988541937918, 140.073618166769, 140.465068264112, 
140.943824496289, 139.503847830698, 139.828469267282, 139.866901113749, 
140.231110786363, 138.700458457692, 140.256192399129, 141.361416033739, 
140.713907096823, 138.980835812608, 138.303403317905, 139.408023758492, 
139.030991942014, 137.83274536635, 140.004326485218, 138.181652816362, 
138.080081349046, 140.177572453938, 144.798191178199, 145.348070693365, 
NA, 142.87268547048, NA, 143.973806261838, 145.697177880129, 
NA, 147.039813464252, 143.441477045751, NA, NA, 148.579113171457, 
NA, 147.138583941394, 146.320431451225, NA, 146.226167224113, 
142.448219150013, NA, 145.885281881276, 144.985690058093, NA, 
144.912584374715, 145.582507664862, 148.121988771797, NA, 146.248506959323, 
NA, 145.151760593063, 149.537625507927, NA, 144.812868524753, 
146.137437723411, 149.767161659034, 150.696017313469, 152.223027191881, 
153.784657674474, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), val2 = c(NA, 
150.213158225837, 140.435520231684, 140.652568715905, 139.045674169061, 
140.072442579546, 140.610737632044, 137.703775588197, 138.106142335419, 
138.812041508755, 140.683604067168, 140.038379585955, 140.880060790739, 
138.942708204401, 138.041374001909, 139.30346343814, 139.652246580653, 
140.711970095059, 139.504007815648, 138.203914835007, 137.584657523716, 
138.547354791723, 138.663066399806, 138.546464167489, 139.327159278758, 
138.505236822648, 138.446301065168, 139.119069068746, 139.88861955423, 
140.430073431184, 139.008313625876, 137.484299942125, 138.41216391793, 
139.133242967442, 140.59965630854, 141.946089778931, 139.224562211565, 
140.076879364045, 139.765358074175, 139.632715461796, 135.802066432194, 
140.129853910036, 140.270979286976, 139.992006786585, 138.808982052871, 
137.756255920595, 139.103795821709, 137.881639260096, 136.807200185064, 
139.397877607737, 137.239641462637, 138.30344591474, 139.844021908301, 
144.416297156919, 143.146988896577, NA, 142.678276011255, NA, 
142.89580356053, 144.437403738214, NA, 144.108154956793, 143.871264835533, 
NA, NA, 145.343486626838, NA, 146.610006556818, 146.45235647302, 
NA, 145.459509738373, 145.022626197219, NA, 144.175461347449, 
142.859062038079, NA, 142.76288245402, 144.170746259675, 146.629646285058, 
NA, 146.095040263688, NA, 144.142762608373, 146.492350679929, 
NA, 143.929271519015, 143.03006571855, 148.272680355239, 154.998098793559, 
150.788837950036, 152.361521480621, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), group = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As I said, it's totally possible I'm missing something or have an error in expectation, but if I right align (by using rollapplyr instead of rollapply), shouldn't I see 5 NAs at the beginning?

Comment: zoo objects align by time point rather than by position so it is only if you are using rollapply with data frames do you need the kludge of NA filling to get alignment. It would be too confusing if it acted differently for different classes so it uniformly drops the points where there is no output unless you use `fill=NA`(or other fill value). Of course if there is an output for every value as with `partial=TRUE` then there is no need to fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("val"), ~
                  zoo::rollapplyr(.x, width = 5L, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA), .names = "{col}_rm"), 
         .by = group)
```

gives

```r
 Timestamp     val1     val2 group  val1_rm  val2_rm
1   2018-03-28 10:56:14       NA       NA     2       NA       NA
2   2018-03-28 10:56:18 152.4206 150.2132     2       NA       NA
3   2018-03-28 10:56:30 140.1681 140.4355     2       NA       NA
4   2018-03-28 10:56:38 141.4961 140.6526     2       NA       NA
5   2018-03-28 10:56:40 140.0825 139.0457     2 143.5419 142.5867
6   2018-03-28 10:56:42 140.0453 140.0724     2 142.8425 142.0839
7   2018-03-28 10:56:44 140.7152 140.6107     2 140.5015 140.1634
8   2018-03-28 10:56:46 137.1136 137.7038     2 139.8905 139.6170
9   2018-03-28 10:56:52 138.1676 138.1061     2 139.2248 139.1078
10  2018-03-28 10:57:00 139.7503 138.8120     2 139.1584 139.0610
11  2018-03-28 10:57:04 140.2160 140.6836     2 139.1925 139.1833
12  2018-03-28 10:57:06 139.7640 140.0384     2 139.0023 139.0688
13  2018-03-28 10:57:10 140.0375 140.8801     2 139.5871 139.7040
14  2018-03-28 10:57:18 139.2009 138.9427     2 139.7937 139.8714
15  2018-03-28 10:57:26 138.7613 138.0414     2 139.5959 139.7172
16  2018-03-28 10:57:30 139.2281 139.3035     2 139.3984 139.4412
17  2018-03-28 10:57:32 140.1324 139.6522     2 139.4720 139.3640
18  2018-03-28 10:57:36 140.6035 140.7120     2 139.5852 139.3304
19  2018-03-28 10:57:38 140.3036 139.5040     2 139.8058 139.4426
20  2018-03-28 10:57:46 138.7944 138.2039     2 139.8124 139.4751
21  2018-03-28 10:57:52 138.5929 137.5847     2 139.6854 139.1314
22  2018-03-28 10:57:54 138.9334 138.5474     2 139.4456 138.9104
23  2018-03-28 10:57:58 136.2310 138.6631     2 138.5711 138.5006
24  2018-03-28 10:58:02 139.3817 138.5465     2 138.3867 138.3091
25  2018-03-28 10:58:04 140.3084 139.3272     2 138.6895 138.5337
26  2018-03-28 10:58:20 137.2237 138.5052     2 138.4156 138.7179
27  2018-03-28 10:58:24 139.5083 138.4463     2 138.5306 138.6976
28  2018-03-28 10:58:26 139.4058 139.1191     2 139.1656 138.7888
29  2018-03-28 10:58:30 140.4982 139.8886     2 139.3889 139.0573
30  2018-03-28 10:58:32 140.5574 140.4301     2 139.4387 139.2779
31  2018-03-28 10:58:34 141.0079 139.0083     2 140.1955 139.3785
32  2018-03-28 10:58:40 138.4693 137.4843     2 139.9877 139.1861
33  2018-03-28 10:58:48 138.9885 138.4122     2 139.9043 139.0447
34  2018-03-28 10:58:52 140.0736 139.1332     2 139.8193 138.8936
35  2018-03-28 10:58:56 140.4651 140.5997     2 139.8009 138.9275
36  2018-03-28 10:59:02 140.9438 141.9461     2 139.7881 139.5151
37  2018-03-28 10:59:20 139.5038 139.2246     2 139.9950 139.8631
38  2018-03-28 10:59:24 139.8285 140.0769     2 140.1630 140.1961
39  2018-03-28 10:59:26 139.8669 139.7654     2 140.1216 140.3225
40  2018-03-28 10:59:30 140.2311 139.6327     2 140.0748 140.1291
41  2018-03-28 10:59:48 138.7005 135.8021     2 139.6262 138.9003
42  2018-03-28 10:59:52 140.2562 140.1299     2 139.7766 139.0814
43  2018-03-28 10:59:56 141.3614 140.2710     2 140.0832 139.1202
44  2018-03-28 11:00:00 140.7139 139.9920     2 140.2526 139.1655
45  2018-03-28 11:00:08 138.9808 138.8090     2 140.0026 139.0008
46  2018-03-28 11:00:14 138.3034 137.7563     2 139.9232 139.3916
47  2018-03-28 11:00:20 139.4080 139.1038     2 139.7535 139.1864
48  2018-03-28 11:00:28 139.0310 137.8816     2 139.2874 138.7085
49  2018-03-28 11:00:32 137.8327 136.8072     2 138.7112 138.0716
50  2018-03-28 11:00:58 140.0043 139.3979     2 138.9159 138.1894
51  2018-03-28 11:20:18 138.1817 137.2396     3       NA       NA
52  2018-03-28 11:20:22 138.0801 138.3034     3       NA       NA
53  2018-03-28 11:20:38 140.1776 139.8440     3       NA       NA
54  2018-03-28 11:20:42 144.7982 144.4163     3       NA       NA
55  2018-03-28 11:20:44 145.3481 143.1470     3 141.3171 140.5901
56  2018-03-28 11:20:45       NA       NA     3 142.1010 141.4277
57  2018-03-28 11:20:47 142.8727 142.6783     3 143.2991 142.5214
58  2018-03-28 11:20:48       NA       NA     3 144.3396 143.4139
59  2018-03-28 11:20:49 143.9738 142.8958     3 144.0649 142.9070
60  2018-03-28 11:20:51 145.6972 144.4374     3 144.1812 143.3372
61  2018-03-28 11:20:52       NA       NA     3 144.1812 143.3372
62  2018-03-28 11:20:53 147.0398 144.1082     3 145.5703 143.8138
63  2018-03-28 11:20:55 143.4415 143.8713     3 145.0381 143.8282
64  2018-03-28 11:20:56       NA       NA     3 145.3928 144.1389
65  2018-03-28 11:21:08       NA       NA     3 145.2406 143.9897
66  2018-03-28 11:21:10 148.5791 145.3435     3 146.3535 144.4410
67  2018-03-28 11:21:11       NA       NA     3 146.0103 144.6074
68  2018-03-28 11:21:12 147.1386 146.6100     3 147.8588 145.9767
69  2018-03-28 11:21:14 146.3204 146.4524     3 147.3460 146.1353
70  2018-03-28 11:21:15       NA       NA     3 147.3460 146.1353
71  2018-03-28 11:21:17 146.2262 145.4595     3 146.5617 146.1740
72  2018-03-28 11:21:19 142.4482 145.0226     3 145.5334 145.8861
73  2018-03-28 11:21:20       NA       NA     3 144.9983 145.6448
74  2018-03-28 11:21:21 145.8853 144.1755     3 144.8532 144.8859
75  2018-03-28 11:21:23 144.9857 142.8591     3 144.8863 144.3792
76  2018-03-28 11:21:24       NA       NA     3 144.4397 144.0190
77  2018-03-28 11:21:26 144.9126 142.7629     3 145.2612 143.2658
78  2018-03-28 11:21:34 145.5825 144.1707     3 145.3415 143.4920
79  2018-03-28 11:21:36 148.1220 146.6296     3 145.9007 144.1056
80  2018-03-28 11:21:37       NA       NA     3 146.2057 144.5211
81  2018-03-28 11:21:39 146.2485 146.0950     3 146.2164 144.9146
82  2018-03-28 11:21:40       NA       NA     3 146.6510 145.6318
83  2018-03-28 11:21:42 145.1518 144.1428     3 146.5074 145.6225
84  2018-03-28 11:21:44 149.5376 146.4924     3 146.9793 145.5767
85  2018-03-28 11:21:45       NA       NA     3 146.9793 145.5767
86  2018-03-28 11:21:48 144.8129 143.9293     3 146.5008 144.8548
87  2018-03-28 11:21:56 146.1374 143.0301     3 146.4099 144.3986
88  2018-03-28 11:22:22 149.7672 148.2727     3 147.5638 145.4311
89  2018-03-28 11:22:30 150.6960 154.9981     3 147.8534 147.5575
90  2018-03-28 11:22:34 152.2230 150.7888     3 148.7273 148.2038
91  2018-03-28 11:22:42 153.7847 152.3615     3 150.5217 149.8902
92                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA       NA       NA
93                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA       NA       NA
94                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA       NA       NA
95                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA       NA       NA
96                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA      NaN      NaN
97                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA      NaN      NaN
98                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA      NaN      NaN
99                 <NA>       NA       NA    NA      NaN      NaN
100                <NA>       NA       NA    NA      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: This looks more like what I would be expecting (though I do not see the leading 5 NAs in group 3), but this also returns NA if a window contains any NA, while I need it to do partial, i.e. if a window contains 3 values and 2 NAs, it should still calculate the mean of those 3 values

Comment: That being said, I think I may have indeed confused myself; I suspect with partial=TRUE it also fills in the typical leading NAs you normally get with rollmeanr?

Comment: See my update. You want this instead? As I said, please provide expected output. You do not get those leading `NA`'s if you add `partial = TRUE` I suspect.

Comment: Note that `rollapply` already works column by column so `across` could be omitted: `df %>% mutate(roll = as.data.frame(rollapplyr(pick(starts_with("val")), 3, mean, fill = NA), .by = group))` or use ``partial=TRUE`` depending on what you want as output.